# Unisharp Laravel File Manajer : upload image success but file not showing

Tags: laravel

I've problem with unisharp laravel file manager.
I have succeeded upload my image but the image is not showing. here is the view in unisharp : [image]

when I preview the picture, it only show this :
[image]

but when I change the URL from `*domain*/storage/photos/750/E-CWBQTVkAAIKTi.jpeg` to `*domain*/storage`, the URL instantly change to `*domain*/public/storage`. and the page show my local folder
[image]

Comment: i tried to log if my `storage_path('framework/views')` exist or not, and it shows exist

Comment: i'm pretty sure it is about the path... it is completely tricky... i suggest open an image on browser and test the url. yout can also move  your images on storage folder. for me, my public folder content is outside of the main folder of project and it is like this : https://myweb.com/MyProjectName/storage/app/public/MyFolder/image.jpg

Comment: in the first image, it clearly show correct folder and subfolder and also the image name. when I upload new image it adds like success, it is only not show the image. but, however I tried to open the image, and its response API show this `path: "/public_html/storage/photos/750/E-CWBQTVkAAIKTi.jpeg"`

Comment: thanks mate for helping me. it done now. i remove the shortcut of `storage` folder in `public` than make it again by running this command `php artisan storage:link`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the shortcut of storage folder in public then make it again by running this command:

```bash
php artisan storage:link
```